# How to throttle data to a given data rate on a TCP Connection

Tags: tcp, language-agnostic, bandwidth-throttling, trafficshaping

There are multiple incoming TCP connections and you need to architect a system that will write to an outgoing TCP connection at a particular data rate. How do you programmatically achieve this. The ordering of the packets from different threads is unimportant, assumptions can be made on that.

Is this just a rate-limiting algorithm? Or are there TCP-related protocol characteristics that can be exploited?

Rejected answer:
Using a queue and a timer to achieve this through the leaky-bucket approach (This was an interview question)

Comment: I feel like the incoming connections and the outgoing connection are related in some way that you failed to mention.

Comment: I don't think they are not related. Multiple income connections. 1 outgoing connection at a given data rate.